# Admob integration on different Android device

Tags: android, admob

I'm new to Android development and my first application is looking good.

Curious if anyone has ran into problems with admob:

I have a ListFragment that displays a list with ads at the top and bottom of the list. The display is fine and everything runs ok except - 
when I click on the ads and after the browser loads up, clicking back does nothing except for "going" back on the browser and it doesn't go back to the app.

Strangely enough this is happening on my Samsung s3 device but not on my HTC device.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Samsung uses their own custom browser (not stock), and its deciding what to do with the back button.  I don't think there's anything you can do-  their browser has the focus, it gets to decide what to do with all IO.  Your app is in the background and doesn't have any say over IO response.